# Saving an sklearn `FunctionTransformer` with the function it wraps

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I am using `sklearn`'s `Pipeline` and `FunctionTransformer` with a custom function

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

This is my code:

```
def f(x):
    return x*2
pipe = Pipeline([("times_2", FunctionTransformer(f))])
joblib.dump(pipe, "pipe.joblib")
del pipe
del f
pipe = joblib.load("pipe.joblib") # Causes an exception
```

And I get this error:

> AttributeError: module '__ main__' has no attribute 'f'

How can this be resolved ?

Note that this issue occurs also in `pickle`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to hack a solution using the `marshal` module (in addition to `pickle`) and override the magic methods `getstate` and `setstate` used by `pickle`.

```
import marshal
from types import FunctionType
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class MyFunctionTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.func = f
    def __call__(self, X):
        return self.func(X)
    def __getstate__(self):
        self.func_name = self.func.__name__
        self.func_code = marshal.dumps(self.func.__code__)
        del self.func
        return self.__dict__
    def __setstate__(self, d):
        d["func"] = FunctionType(marshal.loads(d["func_code"]), globals(), d["func_name"])
        del d["func_name"]
        del d["func_code"]
        self.__dict__ = d
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X):
        return self.func(X)
```

Now, if we use `MyFunctionTransformer` instead of `FunctionTransformer`, the code works as expected:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

@MyFunctionTransformer
def my_transform(x):
    return x*2
pipe = Pipeline([("times_2", my_transform)])
joblib.dump(pipe, "pipe.joblib")
del pipe
del my_transform
pipe = joblib.load("pipe.joblib")
```

The way this works, is by deleting the function `f` from the pickle, and instead `marshaling` its code, and its name.

[`dill`](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) also looks like a good alternative to marshaling

Comment: It should be: del my_transform instead of del f. Would this still work with more than one custom function or nested pipelines?

Comment: True, thanks, I fixed the code snippet. It would work with nested pipelines and anything that's marshallable (not every function is)

Comment: You do intend to load your pipeline in a separate script dont you? So even with your current method, won't you need to have the code of `MyFunctionTransformer` ready somewhere in your memory or imports before calling `joblib.load`?  How is that better than having the code of the `function f` ready in imports. Maybe from another script? Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you agree that if `FunctionTransformer` would be implemented with my additions (namely `setstate` and `getstate`) then pickling would include *all* the required dependencies for the pipeline ?

Comment: Ok, so you want to change the scikit-learn api altogether. But in that case, to include  all the dependencies, you would also need to take care of imports that may be used inside the function, like `np` or `pd` or any other module imported for use in function or else it will throw errors.

Comment: Marshalling all of the dependencies (e.g. `pd`, `np` etc) falls beyond the scope of this StackOverflow question. It is possible with 3rd party libs such as `dill`. 
If you wish to talk about the technical details of the implementation please comment on: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/12905 .

P.S. Now that we are on the same page, I'd appreciate if you'd reverse the downvotes. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant reverse my vote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Now coming to the issue, I tend to agree with scikit-learn devs here to not do this. (1) Because as they mentioned, if this happens at one place, it will need to be done in several other places which take a callable as input (and there are many) to maintain the API.

Comment: (2) Even after all the efforts (if made), the solution you proposed is not complete as I said in my previous comment, the user will need to save the information about the other imports (or maybe other things) used in functions and will have to import/define those things before using the pickled function this way. So in my opinion this tends to be a use-case specific scenario, which `scikit-learn` should not aim for.

Comment: Maybe I am beating around the bush, but first you ask if "I agree that pickling would include _all_ the required dependencies for the pipeline" and then say that "marshalling _all_ of the dependencies falls beyond the scope". Maybe I am critisizing too much ??

Comment: There are alot of edge-cases I do not want to cover, for example, if you marshal an object with one version of python and unmarshal in another version, there can be unexpected results. There are other pypi modules (e.g. `dill`) that aim to solve these issues, and my point is not to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Regarding `sklearn`, when you `pickle` a `TfidfVectotizer` transformer, you expect it to store the `vocab`, `tf` and `idf` in order to work. I think that `FunctionTransformer`, that its sole purpose is to wrap a function with a `transformer` should at least save this function, or raise a warning if that's not possible. P.S. I've edited my Q&A in light of this discussion.