# Scikitlearn - Tensorflow pipeline - How to save pipeline in hd5 / pmml

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, pmml

I have created a pipeline model mixing scikit learn preprocessing and keras.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
clf = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model,epochs=1000,validation_split=0.2, batch_size=100, callbacks=[print_dot,plot_losses], verbose=1)))

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('preprocess',scaler),
    ('clf',clf)
])

import time
start = time.time()
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
```

This code works and I can call the transform pipeline method as well

```
predictions = pipeline.predict(X_test).flatten()
```

The problem is I need to save Pipeline as an HD5 model so that non-pre-processed values can be given to the model during runtime -

Is this possible
if not what is the method of hosting this pipeline?

So the question below only solves the problem of saving just the model without the pre-processing pipeline -
I want to save the pre-processing pipeline as well -

[How to save Scikit-Learn-Keras Model into a Persistence File (pickle/hd5/json/yaml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396042/how-to-save-scikit-learn-keras-model-into-a-persistence-file-pickle-hd5-json-ya#40397312)

[@danyfang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621414/danyfang) was helpful in finding this question

[how to save a scikit-learn pipline with keras regressor inside to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984304/how-to-save-a-scikit-learn-pipline-with-keras-regressor-inside-to-disk)

The problem it stores pipeline as .pkl file separately. So need to see how pk1 is converted to pmml

Comment: There is a similar question with an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984304/how-to-save-a-scikit-learn-pipline-with-keras-regressor-inside-to-disk

Comment: Thanks this does not answer my question of storing the pipeline as hd5 or pmml either . But a good find . including in question

Comment: It is a long shot but this post might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012769/saving-an-sklearn-functiontransformer-with-the-function-it-wraps/54055928#54055928